# when i use any ClickListener in expandable list adapter listview not Expand

Tags: android

***In This code Expandable list will expand***

```
@Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = infleter.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
                ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(expandlist.get(groupPosition).Parent.getCategory());
                ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);


            }



            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            final ArrayList<Expense>expenses=expandlist.get(groupPosition).childItem;
            TextView textexpense=null;
            if (convertView==null) 
            {
                convertView=infleter.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
            }
            textexpense=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textexpense.setText(expenses.get(childPosition).getExpenseName());


            return convertView;
        }
```

***In this Code List Will Not Expand***

```
@Override
        public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = infleter.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
                ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(expandlist.get(groupPosition).Parent.getCategory());
                ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);


            }

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            final ArrayList<Expense>expenses=expandlist.get(groupPosition).childItem;
            TextView textexpense=null;
            if (convertView==null) 
            {
                convertView=infleter.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
            }
            textexpense=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textexpense.setText(expenses.get(childPosition).getExpenseName());


            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the click event of convert view.
Just try to get the onGroupClickListener of your expandable ListView.

```
expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
            long id) {
             //Do Your Task Here.
             }
          }
```

Comment: Simply i want to do like this . if i do normal click on parent item list should be expand . if i do long press that it should display toast message both thing should be run a the same time .  how can i do this ?